# How to find no. of threads of qemu in terminal

Tags: qemu

I am working on threads. I need to find how many threads qemu is using. Any idea about it

Any idea about it.

Comment: have you tried searching dee internets from your facebook surfing machine? what have you found? did you try any of those suggestions? How did they work out?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Follow this in order to find no. of threads used by qemu

http://blog.vmsplice.net/2011/03/qemu-internals-overall-architecture-and.html